# Thread pools not working with large number of tasks

Tags: c++, multithreading, native

I am trying to create a thread pool with native C++ and I am using the code listings from the book "C++ Concurrency in Action". The problem I have is that when I submit more work items than the number of threads, not all the work items get done. In the simple example below, I am trying to submit the runMe() function 200 times but the function is run only 8 times.
It seems like this shouldn't happen because in the code, the work_queue is separate from the work threads. Here is the code:

```
#include "iostream"
#include "ThreadPool.h"
void runMe()
{
    cout << "testing" << endl;
}

int main(void)
{
    thread_pool pool;
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
    {
        std::function<void()> myFunction = [&] {runMe(); };
        pool.submit(myFunction);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

ThreadPool.h class

```
#include <queue>
#include <future>
#include <list>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>
template<typename T>
class threadsafe_queue
{
private:
    mutable std::mutex mut;
    std::queue<T> data_queue;
    std::condition_variable data_cond;
public:
    threadsafe_queue() {}
    void push(T new_value)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mut);
        data_queue.push(std::move(new_value));
        data_cond.notify_one();
    }
    void wait_and_pop(T& value)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mut);
        data_cond.wait(lk, [this] {return !data_queue.empty(); });
        value = std::move(data_queue.front());
        data_queue.pop();
    }
    bool try_pop(T& value)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mut);
        if (data_queue.empty())
            return false;
        value = std::move(data_queue.front());
        data_queue.pop();
        return true;
    }
    bool empty() const
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mut);
        return data_queue.empty();
    }
    int size()
    {
        return data_queue.size();
    }
};

class join_threads
{
    std::vector<std::thread>& threads;
public:
    explicit join_threads(std::vector<std::thread>& threads_) : threads(threads_) {}
    ~join_threads()
    {
        for (unsigned long i = 0; i < threads.size(); i++)
        {
            if (threads[i].joinable())
            {
                threads[i].join();
            }
        }
    }
};

class thread_pool
{
    std::atomic_bool done;
    threadsafe_queue<std::function<void()> > work_queue;
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    join_threads joiner;
    void worker_thread()
    {
        while (!done)
        {
            std::function<void()> task;
            if (work_queue.try_pop(task))
            {
                task();
                numActiveThreads--;
            }
            else
            {
                std::this_thread::yield();
            }
        }
    }
public:
    int numActiveThreads;
    thread_pool() : done(false), joiner(threads), numActiveThreads(0)
    {
        unsigned const thread_count = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
        try
        {
            for (unsigned i = 0; i < thread_count; i++)
            {
                threads.push_back(std::thread(&thread_pool::worker_thread, this));
            }
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            done = true;
            throw;
        }
    }
    ~thread_pool()
    {
        done = true;
    }
    template<typename FunctionType>
    void submit(FunctionType f)
    {
        work_queue.push(std::function<void()>(f));
        numActiveThreads++;
    }
    int size()
    {
        return work_queue.size();
    }
    bool isQueueEmpty()
    {
        return work_queue.empty();
    }
};
```

Any idea on how to use the work_queue properly?

Comment: Not even a `main()`, so that's not a [mcve]. Also, "crashes" is your interpretation, what did you observe? As a new user here, please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: `threadsafe_queue::size()` needs the mutex locking to ensure it see any updates (as you have done for `threadsafe_queue::empty()`)

Comment: Perhaps `task` does not support being moved / copied correctly we need to see the class definition.

Comment: In `threadsafe_queue::wait_and_pop` as this method is holding the lock if the underlying queue is empty on entry the queue can never have a task added as the method is holding the lock. ie if we wait in `threadsafe_queue::wait_and_pop` (because the queue is empty)  `threadsafe_queue::push` on another thread will block.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt thanks for the feedback. I modified the example with a simple main function. This code runs but doesn't run the test function 200 times.

Comment: How do you know? Again, provide observations, like e.g. the produced output. Something that can be verified without any guessing or thinking, just a simple comparison.

Comment: I have updated the text with regards to an example. In the example I am submitting 200 work items to the work_queue but the output prints only 8 times and exits.

Comment: @RichardCritten: the `wait` unlocks the lock while it waits (and relocks it when it wakes up), it's also not being called.

Comment: When `main` returns, `done` is set and all your threads will exit. Maybe you want to wait until the queue drains first? (Also, any point setting `done` should probably also call `notify_all` on the CV (and `wait_and_pop` might want to check that too, if you want your threads use that and spin less).

Comment: Thanks, waiting on the queue to become empty solves the issue of exiting early.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `pool` is destroyed at the end of `main`, your destructor sets `done`, making your worker threads exit.

You should make the destructor (or possibly `main`, if you want to make this optional) wait for the queue to drain before setting the flag.